# SAS temporary DB2 tables - Creating an index

Tags: sas

I have not found a clear answer from my DBA's on this one. I am in a DB2 warehouse...huge tables. I often practice temp tables with an rsubmit, such as...

```
execute (declare global temporary table session.tmp1(task char(9))on commit preserve rows not logged) by db2;
execute (create unique index session.indexa on session.tmp1(task)) by db2;
insert into session.tmp1 select * from connection to db2 
(
select   distinct a.column
from     table1 a
where    ...
for fetch only with ur
);
```

Then when I need that specific group of values, I will join with it...

```
from session.tmp1 t
inner join tablex x on t.task = x.task
```

You will notice that I declared an index (a unique index even). My question is...if the index does not already exist on the original db2 table I am using to build my temp table...will my created index even matter? In addition, a Sr. Analyst advised me that if I "order by" the attribute/column that I am indexing when I build my temp table, it will significantly speed up the join when I use it for additional tables. Can anyone confirm any of these questions? May seem trivial...but I am really looking for some tips on speed, especially when the tables I am hitting are extremely large...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sr. Analyst "Order by" remark:

It depends on the scenario:

> If during creation of the tmp table no order by is used in the plan at all, and in the following join the query plan does not show the need to order the data, the time to order the data in the tmp table will be larger then the time saved in the join.
>
> If in the join the data is ordered before joining, adding an order by might increase the speed of this step (the plan will still show the ordering of the data since it does not know that the data is ordered), but the time gained will most likely be at maximum equal to the time you lost when ordering the tmp table. So when you use your tmp table more then once, it might save you some time. Use it just once, and it is pretty useless.

The index you created:

> The index will help with later joins/where conditions on the tmp table. So if you are using the indexed columns in a join or where: Go for it.
>
> One exception on this is: Sometimes when you join all data in a table, the index is not beneficial. It might be ignored (see the plan again), or it might even slow you down when it is used. This is highly DBMS dependent: Oracle: Full table scan most of the time quicker when joining all rows, MySQL/MariaDB: Even with full joins, adding the index saves you hours, SQL Server determines it by itself pretty good (usually uses the index), DB2: Please post here once you determined this.

Comment: Usually the joining in temp tables for me is repetative per program...so good to know the index is relative. Thanks.